# When to use "this" in Java

Tags: java, this

I apologize for my trivial and probably silly question, but I am a bit confused as to when to use the "this" prefix when using a method or accessing something.

For example, if we look at #4 
here:
http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap_frq_computerscience_12.pdf

And we look at the solutions here:
http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap12_computer_science_a_q4.pdf

We see that one solution to part a) is

```
public int countWhitePixels() { 
int whitePixelCount = 0; 
    for (int[] row : this.pixelValues) { 
      for (int pv : row) { 
      if (pv == this.WHITE) { 
      whitePixelCount++; 
      }
     } 
   } 
return whitePixelCount; 
}
```

while another solution is

```
 public int countWhitePixels() { 
 int whitePixelCount = 0; 
     for (int row = 0; row < pixelValues.length; row++) { 
      for (int col = 0; col < pixelValues[0].length; col++) { 
      if (pixelValues[row][col] == WHITE) { 
      whitePixelCount++; 
     } 
   } 
 } 
 return whitePixelCount; 
}
```

Here is my question. Why is it that they use the "this." prefix when accessing pixelValues and even WHITE in the first solution, but not in the second? I thought "this" was implicit, so am I correct in saying "this." is NOT necessary at all for the first solution?

Thank you SO much for your help :)

Comment: Termionogly please. There are no 'commands' in Java, and 'this' isn't one of them.

Answer (score 6):

With `this`, you explicitly refer to the object instance where you are. You can only do it in instance methods or initializer blocks, but you cannot do this in `static` methods or class initializer blocks.

**When you need this?**

Only in cases when a same-named variable (local variable or method parameter) is *hiding* the declaration. For example:

```
private int bar;
public void setBar(int bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

Here the method parameter is hiding the instance property.

**When coders used to use it?**

To improve readability, it is a common practice that the programmers prepend the `this.` qualifier before accessing an instance property. E.g.:

```
public int getBar() {
    return this.bar;
    // return bar;  // <-- this is correct, too
}
```

Comment: +1 for making including "Readability".

I think code readability can't be stressed enough. 

In the example (a simple accessor method) it's probably overkill, but there are many situations where it does vastly improve readability.

Comment: IMO `return this.bar;` is less readable than `return bar;`. It's just more clutter.

Comment: Agreed @SteveKuo, you should let the IDE take care of differentiating between local variables and class attributes by means of colour schemes, rather than EACH TIME putting the `this.` keyword there manually without actual use other than adding verbosity. @GreyBeardedGeek: do you use notepad or a _proper_ IDE for development? ;-)

Comment: @klaar Every developer prefers his/her own style of code. In this answer I just stated that many developers use `this` in this manner. Also, most code generators I use in different IDEs produce similar code (by prefixing the instance property). So, this is a common practice, but obvoiusly it does not match everyone's flavour.

Comment: Of course it's a personal preference, but it's a silly one just like putting completely obvious comments above each line of code, telling you exactly the same as what you can deduct from reading the code itself. Indeed, a personal preference and not 'wrong' per se, but it's not the cleverest choice imo. And as a last defence: I was just expressing my anger at people who do this using logical arguments. So glad that I found similar opinions!

Answer (score 4):

From [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

**Using this with a Field**

The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field is **shadowed** by a method or constructor parameter.

For example, the Point class was written like this

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

but it could have been written like this:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the name of a method parameter is the same as one of your class data member; then, to refer to the data member, you have to put `this.` before it. For example, in the function `setA()`:

```
public void setA(int a)
{
    this.a = a;
}
```

Since both the data member and the papameter of the method is named `a`, to refer to the data member, you have to use `this.a`. In other cases, it's not required.

And, in your case, I don't think it's necessary to use the `this`, though there is no harm to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to the instance of the class itself. Example:

```
private String name, car;

public class Car(String name, String color)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}
```