# Is there performance difference when using 'this' keyword in Java?

Tags: java, performance

Is there any performance advantage for referring to an instance variable foo as `this.foo` as opposed to simply `foo`?

Comment: Don't you think that if there was a difference, the compiler would resolve by itself?

Comment: It slows down the compiler by a few nanoseconds and the programmer by up to a few seconds, depending on typing speed. Other than that: NO.

Answer (score 2):

There is *no* difference in terms of compiled bytecode or performance<sup>1</sup>.

Using the `this.foo` form is useful when there is a local shadowing `foo` in scope<sup>2</sup> - in which case both forms do something different, so the above statement doesn't apply - but it otherwise has no effect.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Does using the 'this' keyword affect Java performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615780/does-using-the-this-keyword-affect-java-performance?rq=1), which shows that the generated bytecode is identical; and closing for a duplicate!

<sup>2</sup> See [Java - when to use 'this' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429062/java-when-to-use-this-keyword?rq=1) and [When to use "this" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311162/when-to-use-this-in-java) for examples and in-depth explanations.